# To get complete logs of 2 devices using adb

Tags: android, adb, android-logcat

I am testing an app with 2 devices communicating using sockets and monitoring the timestamp values. I select the required device name from the DDMS perspective. But some initial logs are missing(as I have many Log.d statements in the code). I want to store the whole log file after I stop apps in both the phones. Can someone tell me how this can be done in command line using adb? I couldn't find any example for 2 devices.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with two console and get logcat separately for two devices

Get serial no for each devices using `adb devices`

and save logcat as text files

console  1: `adb -s <device1serialNO> logcat  -d > logcat1.txt`

console  2: `adb -s <device2serialNO> logcat  -d > logcat2.txt`

You can filter result for your given tag if needed

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I am unable to see the timestamp field(from the Logcat) in the logs. Please also let me know how can I filter the logs?

Comment: To Filter logcat messages you can use "adb -s <device1serialNO> logcat -s "TAGNAME" -d > logcat1.txt".

Comment: For with timestamp and filter with tag name "adb -s <device1serialNO> logcat -v time -s "TAGNAME" -d > logcat1.txt"

Answer (score 1):

Before launching your application you can start the following command in your terminal:

```
adb logcat <your_application_log_tag>:V *:S > file.txt
```

`<your_application_log_tag>` is a log tag that you use in your application. `*:S` means that you suppress all log outputs from other components. `> file.txt` redirects the output of the command to `file.txt`.

The cause of the problem is that for logging Android has a buffer in RAM and if it becomes full it rewrites the most old entries (FIFO). The command I've provided will store the log on your computer.